# Image compressing in flutter windows application errors

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-windows

i am using flutter_native_image plugin in my flutter windows application to compress the image files before uploading to firebase storage. but i am recieving these errors:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method compressImage on channel flutter_native_image)
> #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:320:7)
>
> #1      FlutterNativeImage.compressImage (package:flutter_native_image/flutter_native_image.dart:22:16)
>
> #2      _addorder2State._uploadImages (package:eaziprep_app_desktop/addorder2.dart:67:29)

this is my source code:

```
for (File imageFile in _imageList) {
      // Compress the image using flutter_native_image
      File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
        imageFile.path,
        quality: 80, // Set the quality (0 - 100)
        targetWidth: 800, // Set the target width
        targetHeight: 800, // Set the target height
      );

      Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("images/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg");

      // Upload the compressed image to Firebase Storage
      UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(compressedFile);

      await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => print('Image uploaded'));

      String downloadURL = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
      imageUrls.add(downloadURL);
    }
```

best regards.